# map of objects with list in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have variable with map of objects with consumer_groups as list(string)
varaibles.tf

```
variable “eventhub_entityname” {
description = “eventhub”
type = map(object({
entity_partition_count = number
entity_message_retention = number
entity_status = optional(string)
storage_capture_needed = bool
capture_encoding = string
capture_interval_in_seconds = optional(number)
capture_skip_empty_archives = optional(bool)
capture_size_limit_in_bytes = optional(number)
consumer_groups = optional(list(string))
}))
}
```

my.auto.tfvars

```
eventhub_entityname = {
firstdemo = {
entity_partition_count = 1
entity_message_retention = 1
storage_capture_needed = true
capture_encoding = “Avro”
consumer_group = [“test1”, “test2”]
}
seconddemo ={
entity_partition_count = 1
entity_message_retention = 1
storage_capture_needed = true
capture_encoding = “Avro”
consumer_group = [“test3”]

}
}
```

now i need to loop first with firstdemo and create test1 and test2 2 consumer groups in it and come back to seconddemo and create test3 consumer group

```
resource "azurerm_eventhub_consumer_group" "example" {
  name                = "acceptanceTestEventHubConsumerGroup"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.example.name
  eventhub_name       = azurerm_eventhub.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  user_metadata       = "some-meta-data"
}
```

Comment: So it should create 3 resources? one for each consumer group?

Comment: in firstdemo  entityhub , it need to have 2 consumer group and in seconddemo entityhub it need to have 1 consumergtoup..  may be i want to create map like { firstdemo:test1, firstdemo:test2, seconddemo:test3} and loop in azurerm_eventhub_consumer_group.example  to create.. am unable to create maps based on above map of objects with list consumer groups.. sorry if i confused u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still not fully understanding your requirement. but based onyour comment if you want to create  map for these that you can easily iterate over in the resource you could do something like below. Note that the map describe in your comment wouldnt work since a map cannot have the same key more than once. But assuming each group name is unique you could do the reverse

```
variable "eventhub_entityname" {
  description = "eventhub"
  type        = map(object({
    entity_partition_count      = number
    entity_message_retention    = number
    entity_status               = optional(string)
    storage_capture_needed      = bool
    capture_encoding            = string
    capture_interval_in_seconds = optional(number)
    capture_skip_empty_archives = optional(bool)
    capture_size_limit_in_bytes = optional(number)
    consumer_groups             = optional(list(string))
  }))
  default =  {
  firstdemo  = {
    entity_partition_count   = 1
    entity_message_retention = 1
    storage_capture_needed   = true
    capture_encoding         = "Avro"
    consumer_groups          = ["test1", "test2"]
  }
  seconddemo = {
    entity_partition_count   = 1
    entity_message_retention = 1
    storage_capture_needed   = true
    capture_encoding         = "Avro"
    consumer_groups          = ["test3"]

  }
}
}

locals {
  group_mappings = merge([for demo, attrs in var.eventhub_entityname: {for group in attrs["consumer_groups"]: group => demo}]...)
}

output "groups" {
  value = local.group_mappings
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Outputs:

groups = {
  "test1" = "firstdemo"
  "test2" = "firstdemo"
  "test3" = "seconddemo"
}
```

Comment: thank u chris..appreciate ur help..let me check and get back to u..